# Mp4 video doesn't play on Safari if not played on Chrome/Firefox first

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, avfoundation, avplayer

This is an odd bug. 
If a video has never been played before, and I try to play it on Safari or AVPlayer on iOS it doesn't work.

If I play it on Chrome/Firefox first, then it is gonna be available on Safari/AVPlayer as well.

The video is coming from **AWS CloudFront** and the URL doesn't change.
It's seems like a MacOS/iOS player issue.

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue? Even I am facing the same